# App crash in ASIHttpRequest class

Tags: ios, iphone, automatic-ref-counting, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I am using ASIHttpRequest class in my application to handle server communication. I am getting my application crash sometimes. Here is screenshot of my crash:

[image]

I cant get it why this is happening. Can any one tell me?

Comment: ASI is really old, no longer under development as such you should switch to something newer/more robust. AFNetworking is a popular choice.

Comment: @CW0007007 but my application is built now and in testing mode I cant change it now...

Comment: It seems you are running your project with ARC enable. So make property of your class's object with `strong`from where `runRequest` is being called.

Comment: Yes you CAN change it now. Since you are relying on an very old framework, that has bugs, is not tested itself on current iOS versions and is no longer in development. You will see crashes and problem because of this!

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes are due to retain/release issues typically. Some tips on how to track them down - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1367/_index.html

You also probably don't want to ship an app with ASIHttpRequest. I believe support died out a long time ago. Look at using the SDK itself or maybe try AFNetworking.